# Compare two rows with different columns of spark in windows function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a typical situation to use Windows function for Spark 2.1.0. Below is the work sample-

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  // Below is REJOIN case when next start date of the updated record is after the previous record's end date
  (1,173777,"7777","2018-12-18","2019-01-04"), 
  (1,173777,"7778","2019-01-05","2019-01-10"), 
  (1,173777,"7779","2019-02-01",null),


  (2,173788,"6666","2004-09-16","2006-03-18"),
  (2,173788,"6668","2018-12-18",null),

  (3,173799,"1111","2002-09-16","2003-03-18"),
  (3,173799,"1112","2007-09-16","2008-03-18"),


  (4,173711,"9566","2009-09-16","2011-03-18"), 
  (4,173711,"9555","2007-09-16","2008-03-18"),

  // Below is UPDATED case when either all record are null with end_date for a window or don't have next record start date > previous end like above
  (5,1737111,"1111","2016-09-26",null), 
  (5,1737111,"1112","2017-09-26",null),
  (5,1737111,"1113","2018-09-26",null),


  (6,1737444,"3334","2004-09-16","2019-02-15"), 
  (6,1737444,"3333","2018-12-18","2019-01-31"),

  (7,1737555,"5555","2009-01-01","2011-02-18"),
  (7,1737555,"5556","2008-12-18","2019-01-31"),
  (7,1737555,"5557","2019-01-01","2019-02-15"),
  (7,1737555,"5558","2019-02-14","2020-02-18"),
  (7,1737555,"5559","2010-01-01","2026-02-18"))
  .toDF("id","user_id", "record_modify_ts", "start_time", "end_time")

val partitionWindowR = Window.partitionBy($"id", $"user_id").orderBy($"record_modify_ts".asc)
```

I have calculated next value of end date like below-

```
val nextStart = lead($"start_time", 1).over(partitionWindowR)
```

I'm trying to calculate `status` as another column with below code-

```
 df.withColumn("next_start", nextStart)
   .withColumn("status", when(to_date($"next_start") >= to_date($"end_time"), lit("REJOIN")).otherwise(lit("UPDATE"))).show
```

Looks like what problem is `null` returned from `next_start` is not `null` for the last record and showing me trouble to assign the status for the record. All I want is an extra column with `status`.

Below is expected output-

```
    /*
+---+-------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| id|user_id|record_modify_ts|start_time|  end_time|next_start| status|
+---+-------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|  4| 173711|            9555|2007-09-16|2008-03-18|2009-09-16| REJOIN|
|  4| 173711|            9566|2009-09-16|2011-03-18|      null| REJOIN| <--
|  3| 173799|            1111|2002-09-16|2003-03-18|2007-09-16| REJOIN|
|  3| 173799|            1112|2007-09-16|2008-03-18|      null| REJOIN| <--
| 15|1737111|            1111|2016-09-26|      null|2017-09-26|UPDATED|
| 15|1737111|            1112|2017-09-26|      null|2018-09-26|UPDATED|
| 15|1737111|            1113|2018-09-26|      null|      null|UPDATED|
| 16|1737444|            3333|2018-12-18|2019-01-31|2004-09-16|UPDATED|
| 16|1737444|            3334|2004-09-16|2019-02-15|      null|UPDATED|
| 17|1737555|            5555|2009-01-01|2011-02-18|2008-12-18|UPDATED|
| 17|1737555|            5556|2008-12-18|2019-01-31|2019-01-01|UPDATED|
| 17|1737555|            5557|2019-01-01|2019-02-15|2019-02-14|UPDATED|
| 17|1737555|            5558|2019-02-14|2020-02-18|2010-01-01|UPDATED|
| 17|1737555|            5559|2010-01-01|2026-02-18|      null|UPDATED|
|  1| 173777|            7777|2018-12-18|2019-01-04|2019-01-05| REJOIN|
|  1| 173777|            7778|2019-01-05|2019-01-10|2019-02-01| REJOIN|
|  1| 173777|            7779|2019-02-01|      null|      null| REJOIN| <--
|  2| 173788|            6666|2004-09-16|2006-03-18|2018-12-18| REJOIN|
|  2| 173788|            6668|2018-12-18|      null|      null| REJOIN| <--
+---+-------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
*/
```

Please help me if possible, I'd appreciate it. Thanks

PS: Other columns maybe wrong here in o/p. I really care about `status`, nothing else.

Comment: Could you please give detail of issue or output what you are getting now

Comment: @saurabhshashank instead of marked `<--` with `REJOIN` I'm getting as `UPDATED` since the final record in the window would have a value of the `null` ass default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your issue,

just need to add null check because for null cases otherwise() will execute always.

```
val df = Seq((1,173777,"7777","2018-12-18","2019-01-04"),(1,173777,"7778","2019-01-05","2019-01-10"),(1,173777,"7779","2019-02-01",null),(2,173788,"6666","2004-09-16","2006-03-18"),(2,173788,"6668","2018-12-18",null),(3,173799,"1111","2002-09-16","2003-03-18"),(3,173799,"1112","2007-09-16","2008-03-18"),(4,173711,"9566","2009-09-16","2011-03-18"),(4,173711,"9555","2007-09-16","2008-03-18"),(5,1737111,"1111","2016-09-26",null),(5,1737111,"1112","2017-09-26",null),(5,1737111,"1113","2018-09-26",null),(6,1737444,"3334","2004-09-16","2019-02-15"),(6,1737444,"3333","2018-12-18","2019-01-31"),(7,1737555,"5555","2009-01-01","2011-02-18"),(7,1737555,"5556","2008-12-18","2019-01-31"),(7,1737555,"5557","2019-01-01","2019-02-15"),(7,1737555,"5558","2019-02-14","2020-02-18"),(7,1737555,"5559","2010-01-01","2026-02-18")).toDF("id","user_id", "record_modify_ts", "start_time", "end_time")
val partitionWindowR = Window.partitionBy($"id", $"user_id").orderBy($"record_modify_ts".asc)
val nextStart = lead($"start_time", 1).over(partitionWindowR)
val df_t =df.withColumn("next_start", nextStart).withColumn("status", when( to_date($"next_start") >= to_date($"end_time"), lit("REJOIN")).otherwise(lit("UPDATE"))).show()
```

Output :

```
+---+-------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------+
| id|user_id|record_modify_ts|start_time|  end_time|next_start|status|
+---+-------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------+
|  4| 173711|            9555|2007-09-16|2008-03-18|2009-09-16|REJOIN|
|  4| 173711|            9566|2009-09-16|2011-03-18|      null|UPDATE|
|  6|1737444|            3333|2018-12-18|2019-01-31|2004-09-16|UPDATE|
|  6|1737444|            3334|2004-09-16|2019-02-15|      null|UPDATE|
|  3| 173799|            1111|2002-09-16|2003-03-18|2007-09-16|REJOIN|
|  3| 173799|            1112|2007-09-16|2008-03-18|      null|UPDATE|
|  5|1737111|            1111|2016-09-26|      null|2017-09-26|UPDATE|
|  5|1737111|            1112|2017-09-26|      null|2018-09-26|UPDATE|
|  5|1737111|            1113|2018-09-26|      null|      null|UPDATE|
|  1| 173777|            7777|2018-12-18|2019-01-04|2019-01-05|REJOIN|
|  1| 173777|            7778|2019-01-05|2019-01-10|2019-02-01|REJOIN|
|  1| 173777|            7779|2019-02-01|      null|      null|UPDATE|
|  7|1737555|            5555|2009-01-01|2011-02-18|2008-12-18|UPDATE|
|  7|1737555|            5556|2008-12-18|2019-01-31|2019-01-01|UPDATE|
|  7|1737555|            5557|2019-01-01|2019-02-15|2019-02-14|UPDATE|
|  7|1737555|            5558|2019-02-14|2020-02-18|2010-01-01|UPDATE|
|  7|1737555|            5559|2010-01-01|2026-02-18|      null|UPDATE|
|  2| 173788|            6666|2004-09-16|2006-03-18|2018-12-18|REJOIN|
|  2| 173788|            6668|2018-12-18|      null|      null|UPDATE|
+---+-------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------+


df_t.withColumn("status_updated",first($"status").over(partitionWindowR)).show()
```

fixed output :

```
+---+-------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------+--------------+
| id|user_id|record_modify_ts|start_time|  end_time|next_start|status|status_updated|
+---+-------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------+--------------+
|  4| 173711|            9555|2007-09-16|2008-03-18|2009-09-16|REJOIN|        REJOIN|
|  4| 173711|            9566|2009-09-16|2011-03-18|      null|UPDATE|        REJOIN|
|  6|1737444|            3333|2018-12-18|2019-01-31|2004-09-16|UPDATE|        UPDATE|
|  6|1737444|            3334|2004-09-16|2019-02-15|      null|UPDATE|        UPDATE|
|  3| 173799|            1111|2002-09-16|2003-03-18|2007-09-16|REJOIN|        REJOIN|
|  3| 173799|            1112|2007-09-16|2008-03-18|      null|UPDATE|        REJOIN|
|  5|1737111|            1111|2016-09-26|      null|2017-09-26|UPDATE|        UPDATE|
|  5|1737111|            1112|2017-09-26|      null|2018-09-26|UPDATE|        UPDATE|
|  5|1737111|            1113|2018-09-26|      null|      null|UPDATE|        UPDATE|
|  1| 173777|            7777|2018-12-18|2019-01-04|2019-01-05|REJOIN|        REJOIN|
|  1| 173777|            7778|2019-01-05|2019-01-10|2019-02-01|REJOIN|        REJOIN|
|  1| 173777|            7779|2019-02-01|      null|      null|UPDATE|        REJOIN|
|  7|1737555|            5555|2009-01-01|2011-02-18|2008-12-18|UPDATE|        UPDATE|
|  7|1737555|            5556|2008-12-18|2019-01-31|2019-01-01|UPDATE|        UPDATE|
|  7|1737555|            5557|2019-01-01|2019-02-15|2019-02-14|UPDATE|        UPDATE|
|  7|1737555|            5558|2019-02-14|2020-02-18|2010-01-01|UPDATE|        UPDATE|
|  7|1737555|            5559|2010-01-01|2026-02-18|      null|UPDATE|        UPDATE|
|  2| 173788|            6666|2004-09-16|2006-03-18|2018-12-18|REJOIN|        REJOIN|
|  2| 173788|            6668|2018-12-18|      null|      null|UPDATE|        REJOIN|
+---+-------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------+--------------+
```

Comment: No, both guys didn't work. Can you please use IDE or console to make it? looks like we are close. The issue seems is if we fix one category then other showing trouble. Maybe you can add "9999-01-01" value if `end_time` is `null` or something arbitrary just to differentiate `end_time` null vs `next_start` null?

Comment: whatever I gave you all data with `id` in one digit (1-5) is the case of `REJOIN` only, and `id` in two digits are from `UPDATED`.  If I apply your logic to my data looks like still needs fixes, `| 15|1737111|            1113|2018-09-26|      null|      null|REJOIN|` ; `16|1737444|            3334|2004-09-16|2019-02-15|      null|REJOIN|`; `17|1737555|            5559|2010-01-01|2026-02-18|      null|REJOIN|` are wrong. Should be the case of `UPDATED` but shows REJOIN.

Comment: BTW this is what I was getting earlier, Those columns are showing problems which are having `null` as `next_start`. Can you make a little fix to come on this?

Comment: In simple words, if I fix `REJOIN` cases for `next_start` as null then last records of `UPDATED` case get wrong. And vice versa for another one.

Comment: Please define REJOIN And UPDATE for userid. I would fix the issue.

Comment: Data Are getting updated as the `record_modify_ts`. REJOIN: end of the next/updated record is after the previous record's end date. The updated record can be null since a user didn't leave the program.  This is the case of having historical dates when joined and left. If join after the previous end of another program then considered as `REJOIN`.

Comment: `UPDATE` is when user don't leave the program and join another program. Never left the program so end date is always null. Could be the case in which end of the next data is more recent date then last record end date. Please check my mocked data. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a ton!. Looks like changing second-time status was the key.